# Having problems starting mysql on mac with mysql.sock.lock

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

I've already searched on this, and tried quite a few things. First, I'm on MacOS, 10.12.3, this is a new install of mysql, 5.7 (they work together, I checked). From the mysql.local.err log:

```
    Could not create unix socket lock file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.lock.
    Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
    Aborting
```

I've looked through other questions about this (and there are a LOT of them) and tried a lot of things. However, most everyone then says to do something like this:

```
    service mysql start
```

At which point I get:

```
    service command not found
```

So that's one thing that I've tried and failed and gotten stuck at.

I spent all yesterday working at this and following different rabbit holes trying to figure this out. I'm new at installing a database, so I'm asking for help. If I've done something stupid - just tell me - I just want to try and get my laptop up and running so I can continue learning coding.

Thank you all kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install MySQL with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (brew install mysql), it is as easy as:

```
$ mysql.server start
```

Comment: That helped! Thank you. I'm having other issues, but they're mysql issues, and I'll research them and work on it. This got me so much further along!